# How do I solve this matrix equation? I am kinda confused about the sum with a scalar part

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

The equation is  XA = A + 3X

A =
\begin{pmatrix}4 & -6 & 2\\-1 & 8 & 0\\-1 & 7 & -2\end{pmatrix}

What I do:
XA - 3X = A
XA - 3X * I = A (I = the identity matrix)
X(A - 3I) = A

But I am not sure It works like that. Then I solve A - 3I by which I mean subtracting
\begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 & 0\\0 & 3 & 0\\0 & 0 & 3\end{pmatrix} from A and the rest is obvious but still I don't think matrix equations work like that. I would appreciate any clues to the right directions or answer if I am doing it right.

Comment: Why do you doubt about your process? What is not clear?

Comment: $X$ is an unknown  matrix with $9$ unknown entries. Your equation $XA=A+3X$  then can be rewritten as a system of $9$ linear equations with $9$ unknowns.

Comment: @SebastiánV.Romero What I ask is if the equation is solved like that. I doubt at the step with (A - 3I) I am subtracting a scalar from matrix which In my knowledge can't be done.

Comment: @markvs I want to get the equation in the form of AX = B and then solve it

Comment: You already have equation $X(A-3I)=A$. Now solve it. But in fact you can solve the original equation without this step.

Comment: As a sanity check, try to compute $A(A-3I)^{-1}$ (solve for $X$) and check if the initial equation holds.

Comment: @markvs I solved it. I just wanted to know if I can do it like that. I guess my approach is correct then? Thanks for responding!

Comment: Yes, $XA-3X=X(A-3I)$.